# Using matrices, what is the general form for solving a series of coupled differential equations?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I have derived two equations describing the forced vibration of a coupled harmonic oscillator system.

Coupled Equations
[image: Coupled Equations]

A colleague of mine suggested using: $Ax = B$. However, I don't know how to implement that to this specific case or if it even applies.

I plan on solving this in Matlab, but would like to know how to arrange these equations into matrix notation to solve for the velocities.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Does my answer settle it for you, onamama? Anything needs explication?

Comment: Are you still here, onamama?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use primes instead of dots for derivatives. I'm going to introduce new letters to stand for your basic functions and their derivatives: $u$ will stand for $x_s$, $v$ for $x_s'$, $w$ for $x_m$, and $z$ for $x_m'$. Then your equations can be rewritten in the form $u'=v$, $v'=au+bv+cw+dz+e$, $w'=z$, $z'=fu+gv+hw+iz+j$ for some constants $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j$. If you let $X$ be the vector $(u,v,w,z)$, then you can write these four linear equations as a matrix equation $X'=AX+B$ for some matrix $A$ and some vector $B$, the entries of $A$ and $B$ being constants.